# Casting with Single<> on RxJava

Tags: reactive-programming, rx-java2

I would like to know if there is a way to do a cast from `Single<Object>` to `Single<CustomClass>`.
I have a class that implements a method that should return a `Single<Customer>`, I implemented the search like here

```
Single.create(single -> {
        CustomerServiceDto customer = mapper.map(customerRepository.findById(id).get(), CustomerServiceDto.class);
        single.onSuccess(customer);
    });
```

There isn't any problem. It's what I need. This create returns me a `Single<Customer>` but when I implement another function to handling an exception

```
Single.create(single -> {
        CustomerServiceDto customer = mapper.map(customerRepository.findById(id).get(), CustomerServiceDto.class);
        single.onSuccess(customer);
    }).onErrorReturn(error -> new CustomerServiceDto());
```

It returns me a `Single<Object>`. Can I do a casting here? To avoid change the method's signature. I tried with the classic `(Single<Customer>) Single<Object> instance`, but it isn't work. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: Casting shouldn't be required here. If you do `Single.<CustomerServiceDto>create(...)`, does that solve the problem?

Comment: Thanks @dano, it does work, I didn't try it. Because I thought it would be `Single<CustomerServiceDto>.create()` XD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was the  @dano's comment. Thanks, @dano.